# src/com.app.main && gen/com.app.main is the same package?

Tags: java, android, package

When we create a simple android app, we can find MainActivity.java in ***src/com.app.main*** and R.java in ***gen/com.app.main*** (Also, you can define another file or package name, but the format is similar). and from all the indication i found in the code, it seems that ***src/com.app.main*** && ***gen/com.app.main*** means the same package. why? IMO package is only a folder, and MainActivity.java is in the folder src/com/app/main, R.java is in the folder gen/com/app/main, obviously two different folders, and i think that two different folders mean two different package, anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, package is not a folder. Source file belongs to the package indicated by the `package` clause at the first line of that file. Creating folder structure that corresponds to the package structure is just a convention.

Secondly, when mapping folders to packages folders are treated as relative to their respective base source folders. In your case there are two source folders: `src` for your sources and `gen` for generated sources, and both folders contain subfolders that correspond to the same package.

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing one is Java package name in src/ and second is android app package name. The folder structure in gen is generated based on the package name defined in the manifest file.

These two could be different also, in that case you will import R with appropriate package name appended to it in the Java files.